# Huawei mediapad t1 7inch

Tags: huawei

I have a problem with my huawei mediapad t1 7 tablet, online videos on youtube and other video sites take long time to start.other smartphones work well on the same wifi network.my system is kitkat and is up to date.i tried all browsers youtube app works well but sometimes there is start and stop
.please help